# Efficient multivariate normal inference

Tags: r, performance, statistics, bayesian, normal-distribution

I'm trying to implement a modified version of a Kalman filter, in which I have a *n*-dimensional Normal prior on my vector of *n* hidden variables, and then a sequence of *m* independent data vectors which are distributed with different-but-known covariance matrices according to the hidden variables.

More formally:

[image]

The generalised solution for the posterior distribution of any given hidden variable conditional on all previous observed variables is:

[image: Solution]

So it is fairly "easy" to compute the final posterior distribution – all you have to do is apply the above transformations iteratively, starting with your prior and using the known covariance matrices and observed values at each step *i*. So a potential way to code this, assuming I have a list `Sigma` with the known covariance matrices, a matrix `O` with the observed value vectors, and the other variables stored in `Lambda`, `Delta`, and `mu`, is:

```
inv_Sigma = solve (Sigma [[1]])
inv_Lambda_plus_Delta = solve (Delta)
Delta_i = solve (inv_Sigma  + inv_Lambda_plus_Delta)
mu_i = Delta_i %*% (inv_Sigma %*% O [, 1] + inv_Lambda_plus_Delta %*% mu)

if (n > 1) {
    for (i in seq (2, n)) {
        inv_Sigma = solve (Sigma [[i]])
        inv_Lambda_plus_Delta = solve (Lambda + Delta_i)
        Delta_i = solve (inv_Sigma + inv_Lambda_plus_Delta)
        mu_i = Delta_i %*% (inv_Sigma %*% O [, i] + inv_Lambda_plus_Delta %*% mu_i)
    }
}
```

However, as the dimension of the vectors grows, having to calculate these matrix inverses iteratively over and over and over gets increasingly computationally expensive, to the point where (for the problem I want to solve) it's prohibitive. Is there a more efficient way to do this calculation, either with some already-existing function or package or with a more efficient implementation of matrix inversion? Is a simulation-based solution better for my problem?

Comment: Does this on the Cholesky decomposition help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14951/efficient-calculation-of-matrix-inverse-in-r

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for math.stackexchange.com or stats.stackexchange.com. That said, take a look at low-rank approximations to the inverse. One way to approach that would be to look at the eigenvectors corresponding to the largest eigenvalues of either the covariance or the inverse covariance (not clear to me which one you should look at). Back in the day there was ARPACK for computing eigen-stuff of a large matrix via iterative algorithms, maybe take a look at that or some more up to date library. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: So while the Cholesky decomposition _does_ accelerate computation by a lot, it's still not quite at the level I'd like it to be, and I wonder whether there are any simulation-based or approximate ways to calculate stuff that are yet more efficient.

Comment: This might be better suited to the [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/), which is more geared to numerical linear algebra stuffs.